# join table and where column similar to other column, while changing column value SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have an issue with my code. This is an SQL issue.

I need to combine two tables. At present I have this code:

```
SELECT calldate,clid, '44'+dst AS      [NumberDialed],dstchannel,billsec,disposition,accountcode,uniqueid,cnam, callRateImport.Description, callRateImport.Code, callRateImport.Day FROM callLogImport
LEFT JOIN callRateImport ON callLogImport.dst LIKE callRateImport.Code + '%'
WHERE
callRateImport.Code(Select Code FROM callRateImport WHERE callLogImport.dst LIKE Code + '%' AND Len(Code) = (SELECT MAX(Len(Code)) FROM callRateImport WHERE callLogImport.dst LIKE callRateImport.Code + '%') )
```

This is combining fine. Now I need to match it to an altered result depending on what the original result is.

I have this code:

```
IF SUBSTRING (dst,1,2)=00

BEGIN

END
```

wrapping the current code. SQL is throwing errors - incorrect Syntax. I have an ELSE IF block of 3 components.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking ? Explain with the data and result expected.

Comment: I need to change the numbers, where string starts with "0" it needs to be matched to the number starting with 44 instead of 0. My previous code only connected to the number if it started also with a 0.

Comment: How do I make the IF ELSE loop work? That is my main issue atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify values based on its current value, you should look at  [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) Statements.

For example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT   ProductNumber, Category =
    CASE ProductLine
       WHEN 'R' THEN 'Road'
       WHEN 'M' THEN 'Mountain'
       WHEN 'T' THEN 'Touring'
       WHEN 'S' THEN 'Other sale items'
       ELSE 'Not for sale'
    END,
 Name
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber;
GO
```

or with searched case expressions:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" = 
     CASE 
        WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'
        WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'
        WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'
        WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'
        ELSE 'Over $1000'
     END
FROM Production.Product
ORDER BY ProductNumber ;
GO
```